# How can I get IDs of items on Canvas uploaded as JSON in Fabric JS?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, fabricjs

I have a canvas and I am loading this canvas from JSON. There are two group elements and they have their own ID (ID: 1047,1048). I keep the ID numbers to be deleted in an array of 1048,1049,1050.

```
var toDelete = ['1048', '1049', '1050'] ;
```

After JSON is loaded, if there is an item belonging to the ID in the array, I want it to be deleted. How can I do that?

According to the comparison, the ID number 1048 should be deleted.
I wrote function such code to throw incoming IDs into an array, but it didn't work.

**[MY PEN](https://codepen.io/burakfguzel/pen/oNLymXJ)**

```
function loadedIdsFunction(){ // I wrote this function to get incoming IDs but it didn't work

  var loadedIds = [];   //IDs of items from JSON Canvas
  document.getElementById("c").fabric = canvas;
  canvas.getObjects().forEach(function(o) {
      if(o.type == 'group'){
         loadedIds.push(o.id); 
      }
    });             
}
```

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

var json = '{"version":"3.1.0","objects":[{"type":"group","version":"3.1.0","originX":"left","originY":"top","left":194,"top":157,"width":40,"height":80,"fill":"rgb(0,0,0)","stroke":null,"strokeWidth":0,"strokeDashArray":null,"strokeLineCap":"butt","strokeDashOffset":0,"strokeLineJoin":"miter","strokeMiterLimit":4,"scaleX":1,"scaleY":1,"angle":0,"flipX":false,"flipY":false,"opacity":1,"shadow":null,"visible":true,"clipTo":null,"backgroundColor":"","fillRule":"nonzero","paintFirst":"fill","globalCompositeOperation":"source-over","transformMatrix":null,"skewX":0,"skewY":0,"id":"1047","objects":[{"type":"rect","version":"3.1.0","originX":"left","originY":"top","left":-20,"top":-15,"width":35,"height":50,"fill":"blue","stroke":"blue","strokeWidth":5,"strokeDashArray":null,"strokeLineCap":"butt","strokeDashOffset":0,"strokeLineJoin":"miter","strokeMiterLimit":4,"scaleX":1,"scaleY":1,"angle":0,"flipX":false,"flipY":false,"opacity":1,"shadow":null,"visible":true,"clipTo":null,"backgroundColor":"","fillRule":"nonzero","paintFirst":"fill","globalCompositeOperation":"source-over","transformMatrix":null,"skewX":0,"skewY":0,"rx":0,"ry":0,"id":"1047"},{"type":"text","version":"3.1.0","originX":"center","originY":"top","left":0,"top":-40,"width":36,"height":20.34,"fill":"red","stroke":null,"strokeWidth":1,"strokeDashArray":null,"strokeLineCap":"butt","strokeDashOffset":0,"strokeLineJoin":"miter","strokeMiterLimit":4,"scaleX":1,"scaleY":1,"angle":0,"flipX":false,"flipY":false,"opacity":1,"shadow":null,"visible":true,"clipTo":null,"backgroundColor":"white","fillRule":"nonzero","paintFirst":"fill","globalCompositeOperation":"source-over","transformMatrix":null,"skewX":0,"skewY":0,"text":"1047","fontSize":18,"fontWeight":"normal","fontFamily":"Quicksand","fontStyle":"normal","lineHeight":1.16,"underline":false,"overline":false,"linethrough":false,"textAlign":"left","textBackgroundColor":"","charSpacing":0,"styles":{}}]},{"type":"group","version":"3.1.0","originX":"left","originY":"top","left":640,"top":473,"width":40,"height":80,"fill":"rgb(0,0,0)","stroke":null,"strokeWidth":0,"strokeDashArray":null,"strokeLineCap":"butt","strokeDashOffset":0,"strokeLineJoin":"miter","strokeMiterLimit":4,"scaleX":1,"scaleY":1,"angle":0,"flipX":false,"flipY":false,"opacity":1,"shadow":null,"visible":true,"clipTo":null,"backgroundColor":"","fillRule":"nonzero","paintFirst":"fill","globalCompositeOperation":"source-over","transformMatrix":null,"skewX":0,"skewY":0,"id":"1048","objects":[{"type":"rect","version":"3.1.0","originX":"left","originY":"top","left":-20,"top":-15,"width":35,"height":50,"fill":"blue","stroke":"blue","strokeWidth":5,"strokeDashArray":null,"strokeLineCap":"butt","strokeDashOffset":0,"strokeLineJoin":"miter","strokeMiterLimit":4,"scaleX":1,"scaleY":1,"angle":0,"flipX":false,"flipY":false,"opacity":1,"shadow":null,"visible":true,"clipTo":null,"backgroundColor":"","fillRule":"nonzero","paintFirst":"fill","globalCompositeOperation":"source-over","transformMatrix":null,"skewX":0,"skewY":0,"rx":0,"ry":0,"id":"1048"},{"type":"text","version":"3.1.0","originX":"center","originY":"top","left":0,"top":-40,"width":36,"height":20.34,"fill":"red","stroke":null,"strokeWidth":1,"strokeDashArray":null,"strokeLineCap":"butt","strokeDashOffset":0,"strokeLineJoin":"miter","strokeMiterLimit":4,"scaleX":1,"scaleY":1,"angle":0,"flipX":false,"flipY":false,"opacity":1,"shadow":null,"visible":true,"clipTo":null,"backgroundColor":"white","fillRule":"nonzero","paintFirst":"fill","globalCompositeOperation":"source-over","transformMatrix":null,"skewX":0,"skewY":0,"text":"1048","fontSize":18,"fontWeight":"normal","fontFamily":"Quicksand","fontStyle":"normal","lineHeight":1.16,"underline":false,"overline":false,"linethrough":false,"textAlign":"left","textBackgroundColor":"","charSpacing":0,"styles":{}}]}],"backgroundImage":{"type":"image","version":"3.1.0","originX":"left","originY":"top","left":0,"top":0,"width":780,"height":646,"fill":"rgb(0,0,0)","stroke":null,"strokeWidth":0,"strokeDashArray":null,"strokeLineCap":"butt","strokeDashOffset":0,"strokeLineJoin":"miter","strokeMiterLimit":4,"scaleX":1,"scaleY":1,"angle":0,"flipX":false,"flipY":false,"opacity":1,"shadow":null,"visible":true,"clipTo":null,"backgroundColor":"","fillRule":"nonzero","paintFirst":"fill","globalCompositeOperation":"source-over","transformMatrix":null,"skewX":0,"skewY":0,"crossOrigin":"","cropX":0,"cropY":0,"src":"https://i1.wp.com/onideal.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/Schlafzimmer-Grundriss-ideale-Position-Bett-Moebel-Kleiderschrank-dreieckchen-4-780x646.jpg?fit=780%2C646&ssl=1","filters":[]}}'
canvas.loadFromJSON(json, () => canvas.renderAll(), (o, object) => {
  // console.log(o, object.on);
  object.on('selected', () => {
    console.log(object.id);
  });
});
//canvas.setBackgroundImage('https://i.hizliresim.com/iBHC0t.jpg', canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));


//var uniqid = "0";
var uniqids = 0;
$("#door").on("click", function(e) {
  rect = new fabric.Rect({
    id: uniqid,
    left: 40,
    top: 40,
    width: 35,
    height: 50,
    fill: 'blue',
    stroke: 'blue',
    strokeWidth: 5,
    strokeUniform: false,
    hasControls: true,
  });

  var uniqid = uniqids.toString();

  var text = new fabric.Text(uniqid, {
    fontSize: 30,
    originX: 'center',
    originY: 'right'
  });

  var group = new fabric.Group([rect, text], {
    left: 0,
    top: 100,
  });

  canvas.add(group);
  uniqids++;


});
//*****************************
canvas.on('mouse:wheel', function(opt) {
  var delta = opt.e.deltaY;
  var zoom = canvas.getZoom();
  zoom *= 0.999 ** delta;
  if (zoom > 20) zoom = 20;
  if (zoom < 0.01) zoom = 0.01;
  canvas.setZoom(zoom);
  opt.e.preventDefault();
  opt.e.stopPropagation();

})

$('#getid').click(function() {
  var activeObject = canvas.getActiveObjects();
  alert(canvas.getActiveObject().id);
});



//***************************************

$("#save").on("click", function(e) {
  $(".save").html(canvas.toSVG());
});

$('#delete').click(function() {
  var activeObject = canvas.getActiveObjects();
  canvas.discardActiveObject();
  canvas.remove(...activeObject);
});
```

```css
#c {
  background-color: grey;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

button {
  padding: 10px 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/3.1.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="door">Door</button>
<button id="delete">Delete Door</button>
<button id="save">Save</button>
<button id="getid">GET ID</button>


<p>Save bastıktan sonra altta SVG dosyası oluşur</p>
<br>
<canvas id="c" width="800" height="800"></canvas>
<br>
<p class="save">
</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter the all the objects based on their id, if the id is in the list, remove the item. Like this:

```js
canvas.getObjects()
  .filter(obj => 
    ['1048', '1049', '1050'].includes(obj.id)
  )
  .forEach(item => canvas.remove(item));
canvas.renderAll();
```

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

var json = '{"version":"3.1.0","objects":[{"type":"group","version":"3.1.0","originX":"left","originY":"top","left":194,"top":157,"width":40,"height":80,"fill":"rgb(0,0,0)","stroke":null,"strokeWidth":0,"strokeDashArray":null,"strokeLineCap":"butt","strokeDashOffset":0,"strokeLineJoin":"miter","strokeMiterLimit":4,"scaleX":1,"scaleY":1,"angle":0,"flipX":false,"flipY":false,"opacity":1,"shadow":null,"visible":true,"clipTo":null,"backgroundColor":"","fillRule":"nonzero","paintFirst":"fill","globalCompositeOperation":"source-over","transformMatrix":null,"skewX":0,"skewY":0,"id":"1047","objects":[{"type":"rect","version":"3.1.0","originX":"left","originY":"top","left":-20,"top":-15,"width":35,"height":50,"fill":"blue","stroke":"blue","strokeWidth":5,"strokeDashArray":null,"strokeLineCap":"butt","strokeDashOffset":0,"strokeLineJoin":"miter","strokeMiterLimit":4,"scaleX":1,"scaleY":1,"angle":0,"flipX":false,"flipY":false,"opacity":1,"shadow":null,"visible":true,"clipTo":null,"backgroundColor":"","fillRule":"nonzero","paintFirst":"fill","globalCompositeOperation":"source-over","transformMatrix":null,"skewX":0,"skewY":0,"rx":0,"ry":0,"id":"1047"},{"type":"text","version":"3.1.0","originX":"center","originY":"top","left":0,"top":-40,"width":36,"height":20.34,"fill":"red","stroke":null,"strokeWidth":1,"strokeDashArray":null,"strokeLineCap":"butt","strokeDashOffset":0,"strokeLineJoin":"miter","strokeMiterLimit":4,"scaleX":1,"scaleY":1,"angle":0,"flipX":false,"flipY":false,"opacity":1,"shadow":null,"visible":true,"clipTo":null,"backgroundColor":"white","fillRule":"nonzero","paintFirst":"fill","globalCompositeOperation":"source-over","transformMatrix":null,"skewX":0,"skewY":0,"text":"1047","fontSize":18,"fontWeight":"normal","fontFamily":"Quicksand","fontStyle":"normal","lineHeight":1.16,"underline":false,"overline":false,"linethrough":false,"textAlign":"left","textBackgroundColor":"","charSpacing":0,"styles":{}}]},{"type":"group","version":"3.1.0","originX":"left","originY":"top","left":640,"top":473,"width":40,"height":80,"fill":"rgb(0,0,0)","stroke":null,"strokeWidth":0,"strokeDashArray":null,"strokeLineCap":"butt","strokeDashOffset":0,"strokeLineJoin":"miter","strokeMiterLimit":4,"scaleX":1,"scaleY":1,"angle":0,"flipX":false,"flipY":false,"opacity":1,"shadow":null,"visible":true,"clipTo":null,"backgroundColor":"","fillRule":"nonzero","paintFirst":"fill","globalCompositeOperation":"source-over","transformMatrix":null,"skewX":0,"skewY":0,"id":"1048","objects":[{"type":"rect","version":"3.1.0","originX":"left","originY":"top","left":-20,"top":-15,"width":35,"height":50,"fill":"blue","stroke":"blue","strokeWidth":5,"strokeDashArray":null,"strokeLineCap":"butt","strokeDashOffset":0,"strokeLineJoin":"miter","strokeMiterLimit":4,"scaleX":1,"scaleY":1,"angle":0,"flipX":false,"flipY":false,"opacity":1,"shadow":null,"visible":true,"clipTo":null,"backgroundColor":"","fillRule":"nonzero","paintFirst":"fill","globalCompositeOperation":"source-over","transformMatrix":null,"skewX":0,"skewY":0,"rx":0,"ry":0,"id":"1048"},{"type":"text","version":"3.1.0","originX":"center","originY":"top","left":0,"top":-40,"width":36,"height":20.34,"fill":"red","stroke":null,"strokeWidth":1,"strokeDashArray":null,"strokeLineCap":"butt","strokeDashOffset":0,"strokeLineJoin":"miter","strokeMiterLimit":4,"scaleX":1,"scaleY":1,"angle":0,"flipX":false,"flipY":false,"opacity":1,"shadow":null,"visible":true,"clipTo":null,"backgroundColor":"white","fillRule":"nonzero","paintFirst":"fill","globalCompositeOperation":"source-over","transformMatrix":null,"skewX":0,"skewY":0,"text":"1048","fontSize":18,"fontWeight":"normal","fontFamily":"Quicksand","fontStyle":"normal","lineHeight":1.16,"underline":false,"overline":false,"linethrough":false,"textAlign":"left","textBackgroundColor":"","charSpacing":0,"styles":{}}]}],"backgroundImage":{"type":"image","version":"3.1.0","originX":"left","originY":"top","left":0,"top":0,"width":780,"height":646,"fill":"rgb(0,0,0)","stroke":null,"strokeWidth":0,"strokeDashArray":null,"strokeLineCap":"butt","strokeDashOffset":0,"strokeLineJoin":"miter","strokeMiterLimit":4,"scaleX":1,"scaleY":1,"angle":0,"flipX":false,"flipY":false,"opacity":1,"shadow":null,"visible":true,"clipTo":null,"backgroundColor":"","fillRule":"nonzero","paintFirst":"fill","globalCompositeOperation":"source-over","transformMatrix":null,"skewX":0,"skewY":0,"crossOrigin":"","cropX":0,"cropY":0,"src":"https://i1.wp.com/onideal.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/Schlafzimmer-Grundriss-ideale-Position-Bett-Moebel-Kleiderschrank-dreieckchen-4-780x646.jpg?fit=780%2C646&ssl=1","filters":[]}}'
canvas.loadFromJSON(json, () => {
  canvas.getObjects()
    .filter(obj => ['1048', '1049', '1050'].includes(obj.id))
    .forEach(item => canvas.remove(item));
  canvas.renderAll();
}, (o, object) => {
  // console.log(o, object.on);
  object.on('selected', () => {
    console.log(object.id);
  });
});
//canvas.setBackgroundImage('https://i.hizliresim.com/iBHC0t.jpg', canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));


//var uniqid = "0";
var uniqids = 0;
$("#door").on("click", function(e) {
  rect = new fabric.Rect({
    id: uniqid,
    left: 40,
    top: 40,
    width: 35,
    height: 50,
    fill: 'blue',
    stroke: 'blue',
    strokeWidth: 5,
    strokeUniform: false,
    hasControls: true,
  });

  var uniqid = uniqids.toString();

  var text = new fabric.Text(uniqid, {
    fontSize: 30,
    originX: 'center',
    originY: 'right'
  });

  var group = new fabric.Group([rect, text], {
    left: 0,
    top: 100,
  });

  canvas.add(group);
  uniqids++;


});
//*****************************
canvas.on('mouse:wheel', function(opt) {
  var delta = opt.e.deltaY;
  var zoom = canvas.getZoom();
  zoom *= 0.999 ** delta;
  if (zoom > 20) zoom = 20;
  if (zoom < 0.01) zoom = 0.01;
  canvas.setZoom(zoom);
  opt.e.preventDefault();
  opt.e.stopPropagation();

})

$('#getid').click(function() {
  var activeObject = canvas.getActiveObjects();
  alert(canvas.getActiveObject().id);
});



//***************************************

$("#save").on("click", function(e) {
  $(".save").html(canvas.toSVG());
});

$('#delete').click(function() {
  var activeObject = canvas.getActiveObjects();
  canvas.discardActiveObject();
  canvas.remove(...activeObject);
});

/*
canvas.on('mouse:over', function(e) {
    e.target.set('fill', 'red');
    canvas.renderAll();
  });
  canvas.on('mouse:out', function(e) {
    e.target.set('fill', 'green');
    canvas.renderAll();
  });
*/
```

```css
#c {
  background-color: grey;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

button {
  padding: 10px 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/3.1.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="door">Door</button>
<button id="delete">Delete Door</button>
<button id="save">Save</button>
<button id="getid">GET ID</button>


<p>Save bastıktan sonra altta SVG dosyası oluşur</p>
<br>
<canvas id="c" width="800" height="800"></canvas>
<br>
<p class="save">
</p>
```

https://codepen.io/moshfeu/pen/gOMBQqL?editors=0010